# GitHub does not recognize changes from a reverted pull request

Tags: git, github, git-merge

I'm working on a Git branch called `bug-fix-1`, which I created based off `integration` branch. There was another branch `bug-fix-2` which was merged into `integration` branch and then we reverted the changes (all were done on Github).

Now when I put up a new pull request to merge my `bug-fix-1` into `integration`, I expect to see the changes which I pulled from `bug-fix-2`. But no, I can't see any of them, the pull request only show the changes I made on `bug-fix-1`.

Any solution on how do I pull in the changes from `bug-fix-2` into my branch and merge them together to `integration` ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is an interesting feature of Git, and not such a bad one once you realize what is happening.

Git tracks commits by commit hash, and from the history `hot-fix-2` is already present.  Git also knows that the reversion has been applied, but it doesn't really see it as backing out the original commit.  Instead, it's just another commit that happens to apply the same diff in reverse, and it has it's own commit hash too.

In order to allow Git to see the changes, you have one of several choices:

1. Revert the revert.  As weird as it sounds, it works.  This says to introduce a new commit that contains the reverse diff.  That commit is not present on the integration branch, and so Git will see it as a change to be brought in.
2. You can cherry pick the original commit, but you'll need a special option:

   ```
   git cherry-pick --keep-redundant-commits COMMIT_HASH
   ```

   where `COMMIT_HASH` introduces the original bug fix.

There are other ways to help do this too, but they're a bit more complicated and involve using `git rebase`.  I think the above techniques are probably the most straight-forward.

Comment: I would personally prefer `git checkout bug-fix-2 && git rebase integration`, but if there are any merge conflicts... (1) may be the best option.

Comment: That won't work.  It'll drop the commit because it already exists in the integration branch.

Comment: does not work, I have tried using cherry-pick and I saw no line change within git. Will read further into --keep-redundant-commits behavior but as far as pushing back reverted changes this is not the solution.

Comment: @mibbit You'll have to provide more context about what is going on.  It absolutely does work, but I suspect there's something different about your specific setup that makes this different for you.  For example, you might think that specifying a branch name will select all commits on that branch, which it does not.  Can you provide a Gist on GitHub with an example of the problem?  I'll also add that it appears that Git has gotten smarter in some way (I'll have to dig into it) and you may not need the option in cases where you used to.

Comment: @mibbit Also keep in mind that if the corresponding fix was introduced some other way (perhaps someone else fixed the problem) then that part of the diff may be left out, or the commit may be dropped all together if that was the entirety of the cherry-picked commit (without `--keep-redundant-commits` and you should see a warning, unless you turned them off) or you may have an empty commit (with `--keep-redundant-commits`).

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I have a slightly more complicated [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051144/git-merge-pr-of-previously-reverted-commits-but-not-all-the-reverted-commits) if you have the time and the inclination

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution which solved this for me was doing `git commit --amend` on the offending commit and changing the description a bit. This changed the commit hash, making it a different commit and GitHub started seeing it as new.