# git merge PR of previously reverted commits (but not all the reverted commits)

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-merge, git-rebase, git-revert

I have reviewed multiple similar questions and responses that haven't worked for my situation.

Most recently, ["Github does not recognize…"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516743/github-does-not-recognize-changes-from-a-reverted-pull-request) in 2017

### I have the situation that

- branch A -> B
- B (adds 100 commits)
- B -> C (adds 1 commit)
- B (adds another 100 commits)
- *accident*: B merges to A via PR (w/ 200 commits)
- *remedy*: revert that PR (w/ 1 commit)
- **desire**: merge C to A

### thoughts/attempts

- PR (C -> A) does not see changes
- *sidebar*: PR (A -> C) will try to revert the relevant changes from C - *this defines the desired effort, but in reverse*
- Creating C', rebasing C from A, PR does not see changes *(because the merge/revert didn't involve C)*
- Can't revert the revert (option 1 from [above link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516743/github-does-not-recognize-changes-from-a-reverted-pull-request)), this would include unwanted B content
- Do I have to cherry-pick?  *(the reverted PR won't list all the commits, only shows 99, then fails on the "show all")*

### Is this a solution/workaround:

- rename A -> D; *D would likely be unused after that*
- rename C -> A
- if so, where does that leave B, whose work needs to move into A eventually?

#### extra points question, followup on above workaround

- If you have Azure git branch policies, do they belong to a **branch** or a **branch name**?

---

For those who need the concrete:

- A - `master`
- B - `develop`
- C - `1.3` release branch
- D - `1.2` release (which doesn't exist as a branch currently, just tags 1.2.0,…, and likely wouldn't be used)

---

**Note**: In our environment, corporate had branch A locked down such that I could not `push -f` to it directly, nor could I `git reset --hard` on the server.

If these had been options, I would have done so immediately.

Having run aground on this, I will know next time (hopefully which never comes) that I will contact the DevOps team immediately to get temporary access to the branch that is needed and use the tools the way they want to be used. The revert of a commit was very undesirable.

Comment: How did you do the revert?

Comment: When you say you want to merge C to A, do you want to bring in the 100 commits from B?

Comment: @Schwern The revert was done on the server in Azure; there's a menu item in the tri-dot menu on the right to "revert" the PR. The multi commit PR is reverted with a single commit.

Answer (score 1):

Let's draw out your repository so we're all on the same page.

> - branch A -> B
> - B (adds 100 commits)
> - B -> C (adds 1 commit)
> - B (adds another 100 commits)

I'm not going to write out 100 commits, 2 is fine.

```
1 - 2 - 3 [A]
         \
          4 - 100 - 5 - 200 [B]
                \
                 7 [C]
```

> - accident: B merges to A via PR (w/ 200 commits)

```
1 - 2 - 3 ------------------ M [A]
         \                 /
          4 - 100 - 5 - 200 [B]
                \
                 7 [C]
```

> - remedy: revert that PR (w/ 1 commit)

```
1 - 2 - 3 ------------------ M - R [A]
         \                 /
          4 - 100 - 5 - 200 [B]
                \
                 7 [C]
```

The problem is now your history of A is polluted with all this junk from B, then a huge reversion. That's going to cause all sorts of headaches.

I would recommend cleaning up your history by resetting A to before the merge and reversion and [force pushing](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/) that.

- `git checkout A`
- `git reset --hard A~2`
- `git push --force-with-index`.

`A~2` is the second commit before A, following only its first parents. That would be commit 3 in the diagram above.

With that done you're back to before the goof.

```
1 - 2 - 3 [A]
         \
          4 - 100 - 5 - 200 [B]
                \
                 7 [C]
```

> - desire: merge C to A

Depends on what that means.

Does C depend on its portion of B? Do you want to merge 4 and 100? Then merge C. After C is merged, rebase B onto A.

```
$ PR(C->A)
$ git checkout A
$ git pull
$ git checkout B
$ git rebase A

1 - 2 - 3 -----------[A]
         \           / \
          4 - 100 - 7   5 - 200 [B]
```

Does that one commit in C stand alone? Cherry pick it onto A and merge.

```
$ git rebase --onto A C~ C
$ git checkout A
$ git merge --no-ff C
          7' [C]
         / \
1 - 2 - 3 -- [A]
         \
          4 - 100 - 5 - 200 [B]
```

---

Final piece of advice, if you're really putting 200 commits in a branch your branches are too large. Cut your work down into smaller chunks. Consider adopting the [Feature Branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) or [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) workflows.

Comment: yes, 200 commits was an exaggeration, but i wanted to make the point that the amount of work there wasn't desirable to cherry-pick (however we did hit the 100 commit limit because of some work that should have been squashed but wasn't); Depends on what "merge C to A" means: yes, I want 4, 100, & 7 to be merged; your steps make sense to me, thanks - i'll just need to get the restriction on the A branch temporarily removed (`git push -f` is not allowed).

Comment: @bshirley Cherry pick will take a range of commits, so the number of commits does not matter.